# how to manually read the java bytecode for understanding purposes only?

Tags: java, bytecode, .class-file

I was reading this [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode) on how some code is translated to `Java bytecode`.
I came across this example:

```
Consider the following Java code:

  outer:
  for (int i = 2; i < 1000; i++) {
      for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
          if (i % j == 0)
              continue outer;
      }
      System.out.println (i);
  }

A Java compiler might translate the Java code above into byte code as follows, 
assuming the above was put in a method:

  0:   iconst_2
  1:   istore_1
  2:   iload_1
  3:   sipush  1000
  6:   if_icmpge       44
  9:   iconst_2
  10:  istore_2
  11:  iload_2
  12:  iload_1
  13:  if_icmpge       31
  16:  iload_1
  17:  iload_2
  18:  irem
  19:  ifne    25
  22:  goto    38
  25:  iinc    2, 1
  28:  goto    11
  31:  getstatic       #84; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  34:  iload_1
  35:  invokevirtual   #85; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
  38:  iinc    1, 1
  41:  goto    2
  44:  return
```

1. I do not understand a single line of the `bytecode.` I want to understand some part of it if not all. or what some of these lines mean such as `iconst_2`?
2. is `bytecode` and `.class` file same or `.class` files contains `bytecode?`. The picture below shows both `.class` and `bytecode` are same
3. If they are different, how is `bytecode` extracted from `.class` files by the `JVM`?

some of the posts in SO talk about `bytecode` in general, but I do not see any post that explains the relationship between `class`and `bytecode` if any and how to read `bytecode` contents  as a user (not as a JVM).[image]

Comment: [Bytecode instruction listing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings)

Comment: "I do not understand a single line of the bytecode. I want to understand some part of it if not all. or what some of these lines mean such as iconst_2?" - how is SO appropriate for this sort of question? Read [the JVM specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/). It will probably answer your other questions too.

Comment: @millimoose: I need a start from where I can pick up. like how Sotirios provided a link. everyone is not expert like you and thats why this forum is for..

Comment: Another thing you should do is write code, compile it, then decompile it using `javap -c` and see how the instructions correspond to your original code.

Comment: @millimoose: This is a good suggestion. I will try it.

Comment: @user1988876 The wiki article has a link of references under it, and a bunch of related articles. The instruction listing and the JVM spec are there too. And one on [Java `.class` files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file).

Comment: If you don't already know an assembly language, Java bytecode probably isn't the place to start. Find a book on MIPS Assembly Language and read up. (You could do x86 assembly if you prefer).

Comment: @vangelion - I'd go with MIPS or maybe 8086. x86 and amd64 are pretty much insane. (For good evolutionary reasons, but still too bloated for learning about concepts.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes I find there is an assumption it has to be terribly complication when it is not.  It is actually very simple.

> I do not understand a single line of the bytecode. I want to understand some part of it if not all. or what some of these lines mean such as iconst_2?

`iconst_2` stands for the integer constant 2

> is bytecode and .class file same or .class files contains bytecode?.

The .class contains more than byte code.  It also contains some constants e.g. String literals and large primitives.  However, you can treat them as one and the same.

> The picture below shows both .class and bytecode are same

The diagram is a simplified view.  In simple terms they are the same thing.

> If they are different, how is bytecode extracted from .class files by the JVM?

A .class has a [specific format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se6/html/ClassFile.doc.html) which if you follow that format you will find the byte code.  As you can see there is more than just byte code in the file, but the byte code is the only bit you should care about.  (Actually you shouldn't really care about the byte code in 99% of cases)

From the Class file format linked above.

> A class file consists of a single ClassFile structure:

```
ClassFile {
    u4 magic;
    u2 minor_version;
    u2 major_version;
    u2 constant_pool_count;
    cp_info constant_pool[constant_pool_count-1];
    u2 access_flags;
    u2 this_class;
    u2 super_class;
    u2 interfaces_count;
    u2 interfaces[interfaces_count];
    u2 fields_count;
    field_info fields[fields_count];
    u2 methods_count;
    method_info methods[methods_count];
    u2 attributes_count;
    attribute_info attributes[attributes_count];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, though I am not totally clear how this bytecode is intepreted by JVM, nor something like `U4 magic`, this has given me some good foundation, on which I can build on.

Comment: The ClassFile spec URL shared in the answer is not working now. This is the latest URL. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se6/html/ClassFile.doc.html
I tried editing the answer, but stackoverflow won't let me add edits unless the edit diff is atleast 6 characters.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to learn about bytecode and the classfile format is to just read the JVM specification. It's freely available online and not that hard to understand (you can skip all the Prolog junk).  That's how I got started. After that, it's just a matter of practice and poking around. You can see how it's used in practice by compiling and disassembling various classes.

Technically, bytecode only refers to the actual instructions in the Code attributes, but it's pretty much meaningless without the rest of the classfile, so usually when I say bytecode, I'm referring to the entire classfile format.

I also wrote a bytecode tutorial from the perspective of writing bytecode in Krakatau assembler. Unfortunately, it doesn't go very far because I stopped writing it due to lack of interest, but it may still help. You can find it [here](https://greyhat.gatech.edu/wiki/index.php?title=Java_Bytecode_Tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

I could recommend a book "Principles of Computer Organization and Assembly Language":

> Today’s incoming students are more likely to be exposed to Java than
>   ever before. Focusing on a modern architecture (the Java Virtual
>   Machine, or JVM), this text provides a thorough treatment of the
>   principles of computer organization in the context of today’s portable
>   computer. Students are given simple but realistic examples to gain a
>   complete understanding of how computation works on such a machine.
>   Juola makes the material useful and relevant in a course that is often
>   difficult for second-year CS students.